# Запрос в запросе или получение данных из двух таблиц mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильнее организовать? Есть код который выводит данные  из таблицы:

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $db   = '';
    $user = '';
    $pass = '';
    $charset = 'utf8';
    $dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
    $opt = [
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    ];
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t = ".$_GET['id']."");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Номер процесса:</td>
    <td>".$row['id_t']."</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Процесс:</td>";
    $stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM process WHERE id_pr = ".$row['process_t']."");
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "
    <td><select name='process_t'>
      <option>".$row['name_pr']."</option>";    }
echo $row['id_t'];
    }
    ?>
```

Но почему то я не могу получить данные `echo $row['id_t'];` из первого цикла после второго. В чем может быть проблема? Правильно ли сделано? Я так понимаю что цикл в цикле плохо и не лучше ли будет вывести информацию сразу с двух таблиц? Если да то как это сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: оба запроса в одной переменной `$stmt`. второй запрос просто затирает первый. назовите переменные уникально и заработает.

Comment: @Lexx918 Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну конечно ничего не получится вы же переменную в вложенном цикле перезаписали.
сделайте примерно так

```
$stmt = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM task WHERE id_t = " . $_GET['id'] . "");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>Номер процесса:</td>
    <td>" . $row['id_t'] . "</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<td>Процесс:</td>";
    $stmt2 = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM process WHERE id_pr = " . $row['process_t']);
    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {
        echo "
    <td><select name='process_t'>
      <option>" . $row2['name_pr'] . "</option></td>";
    }
    echo $row['id_t'];
}
```

и не забывайте о закрывающем тэге **`</td>`**

Comment: Спасибо большое.